# cannot populate 2 colours in mapkit

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mapkit

Somebody please help.. =(

I tried numerous methods to no avail. In my _annotation2 array there are 18 clinics pinpoints and 1 user which I need to populate on the map. However, no matter how I change the codes the pinpoint always come out to be the same color. I am at end wits as i have explored this for a long time with numerous tutorials with no avail.

can some1 plz guide me along.. below is my method to customize the map.. Somebody save me =(

```
 - (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
//NSLog(@"welcome into the map view annotation");

for(int i = 0; i<[_annotation2 count]; i++){
    MyAnnotation* a = [_annotation2 objectAtIndex:i];
    MKPinAnnotationView *pinView=[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:a reuseIdentifier:[annotation title]];
    pinView.animatesDrop=YES;
    pinView.canShowCallout=YES;
    pinView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorRed;
    return [pinView autorelease];

    UIButton* rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
    [rightButton setTitle:annotation.title forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [rightButton addTarget:self
                    action:@selector(showDetails:)
          forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    pinView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;

    UIImageView *profileIconView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"profile.png"]];
    pinView.leftCalloutAccessoryView = profileIconView;
    [profileIconView release];


    return pinView;

}

        MyAnnotation *b = [_annotation2 objectAtIndex:[_annotation2 count ]-1];

        MKPinAnnotationView *pinView2=[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:b reuseIdentifier:[annotation title]];
        pinView2.animatesDrop=YES;
        pinView2.canShowCallout=YES;
        pinView2.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorGreen;
        return [pinView2 autorelease];

        UIButton* rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
        [rightButton setTitle:annotation.title forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [rightButton addTarget:self
                        action:@selector(showDetails:)
              forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        pinView2.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;

        UIImageView *profileIconView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"profile.png"]];
        pinView2.leftCalloutAccessoryView = profileIconView;
        [profileIconView release];


        return pinView2;
```

}

I try this new set of codes but it still doesnt work =(

Comment: Why are you always using the last annotation for the annotation view?  Do you have a property in your MyAnnotation class to tell whether the annotation is a "clinic" or the "user"?

Comment: I do not have... sorry i am a noob.. how do i go about doing that?

Comment: Show your MyAnnotation.h and the code where you create the annotations and call addAnnotation or addAnnotations.

Answer (score 0):

try identifying annonation by identifier. for example

```
if(identifier == clinic) pin.color = red;
else if(identifier == other) pin.color = blue;
```

Comment: i try this new set of codes but it still doesnt work.. I am really desperate already =(

Comment: @Luck Yong, it should be obvious that this is just pseudo code. It's not going to work if you just paste it. Read the pseudo code here, and apply it to your own code.